# Sorting values by property from cfoutput

Tags: sorting, coldfusion, product, cfquery

This question for cold fusion programmers, and will be probably asked by me wrongly, because it is open question and actually can't be answered, coz u and me will be in a lack of inf about it :) But still all i need is just a hint or guess about it, so that i can understand and move on to achieve my aim.

So here comes the question:
I have the coldfusion output script

`<cfquery datasource="#dsn2#">SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCT_ID = #PRODUCT_ID#</cfquery>`

where some products are displayed, and all i need is to sort them by the property for example `is_purchase` whose values can be 0 or 1, plus i have a checkbox:

`<input type="checkbox" name="is_purchase_stock" value="1" <cfif isdefined("attributes.is_purchase_stock")>checked</cfif> onClick="sayfalama.submit();">`

There are actually functions smth like this(is_saleable_stock), u can see it from the all the script of the whole page with products:
http://vteam.net.ru/_fr/4/list_prices.cfm

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want ORDER BY, something like this:

```
<cfquery datasource="#dsn2#">
    SELECT * FROM PRODUCT 
    WHERE PRODUCT_ID = #PRODUCT_ID#
    ORDER BY is_purchase <cfif StructKeyExists(attributes, "is_purchase_stock")>ASC<cfselse>DESC</cfif>
</cfquery>
```

EDIT. This is a reply to the question in a comment:

```
<cfquery datasource="#dsn2#">
    SELECT * FROM PRODUCT 
    WHERE PRODUCT_ID = #PRODUCT_ID#
    AND is_purchase = <cfif StructKeyExists(attributes, "is_purchase_stock")>1<cfselse>0</cfif>
</cfquery>
```

Comment: thank you! but will it display the ones i want and erase the products i don't want to see? and will it work if the checkbox's value is 1 and won't work if the value of checkbox is 0?!

Comment: This is not actually "sorting" values, rather filtering. See updated answer, possibly this is what you need.